Slow Ubuntu with ASRock Wrx80 Creator r2
I just upgraded to an ASRock Wrx80 Creator r2 and a Threadripper Pro 3995wx.
Now Ubuntu 22.04 is slower than Windows 10 and 11. I installed it several times. Then I tried Ubuntu 24.04, and that's slow like it's sleeping.
The second problem is that sometimes the network disappears. Restarting Networkmanager doesn't help. Adding a network manually is impossible because there is no network hardware detected. Only a new install solves the problem, and if I update the software then the problem reappears.
Now Ubuntu 22.04 without any updates is running the first day.
This week I must decide to use the motherboard or swap it with another one,
maybe an ASUS Wrx80 Sage Wifi 2 motherboard that has other issues with Linux.
It's not the "slow Ubuntu" issue described by some users where everything starts slowly. My issue is the lower all-around performance. Meshing a special stl-part is slower, running xmr-bench is slower, and recoding a video is slower. With the same programs in running Windows it is much faster.
